# How to get RMSE from scipy.optimize.leastsq module

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Can I get the vaule of RMSE from scipy.optimize.leastsq module ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a little example using `leastsq`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import collections

x = np.array([821,576,473,377,326,300])
y = np.array([255,235,208,166,157,140])

def sigmoid(p,x):
    x0,y0,c,k=p
    y = c / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) + y0
    return y

def residuals(p,x,y):
    return y - sigmoid(p,x)

Param=collections.namedtuple('Param','x0 y0 c k')
p_guess=Param(x0=600,y0=200,c=100,k=0.01)
p,cov,infodict,mesg,ier = optimize.leastsq(
    residuals,p_guess,args=(x,y),full_output=1,warning=True)
p=Param(*p)
xp = np.linspace(100, 1600, 1500)
print('''\
x0 = {p.x0}
y0 = {p.y0}
c = {p.c}
k = {p.k}
'''.format(p=p))
```

You could compute the residuals this way:

```
resid=residuals(p,x,y)
print(resid)
# [ 0.76205302 -2.010142    2.60265297 -3.02849144  1.6739274 ]
```

But you don't have to compute `resid` -- `infodict['fvec']` already contains the info.

```
print(infodict['fvec'])
# [ 0.76205302 -2.010142    2.60265297 -3.02849144  1.6739274 ]

chisq=(infodict['fvec']**2).sum()
# dof is degrees of freedom
dof=len(x)-len(p)
rmse=np.sqrt(chisq/dof)
print(rmse)
# 5.40092057562
```